# MySQL - Insert comma separated list into normalized tables via stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, csv, insert

I have 3 tables in my database,

- `posts` with the columns `post_id`, `post_title`, and `post_text`
- `tags` with the columns `tag_id` and `tag_text`
- `post_tag` with the columns `post_id` and `tag_id`

I want to write a stored procedure for creating a new post. This post may have any number of tags. If the tag does not exist yet, it should be added to the `tags` table.

Now my problem is, that I'm getting the tags as a comma separated list (e.g. "tag1,tag2,tag3"). What is the best approach to make one row in the table out of each of these values.

My ideas up until now were:

- Splitting the post creation in multiple stored procedures and calling one for every tag.
- Using some kind of explode function on the string in the DB and using a loop to insert every resulting tag (I don't even know if this is possible).
- Dropping the stored procedure and putting together the whole statement as a string (I'd rather not do that).
- Finding a way to bring MySQL to accept variable parameter lists.

Is there any other / better way to make this work, or what's the best approach to this problem?

Comment: someone had a solution for this yesterday i will look if no one answers