# MySQL: stored procedure to split column(with delimiters) and insert into new table

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, split, database-normalization

There is a un normalized table in my database with name `details` structure and sample data as below(apologies for image, just thought it would be more comprehensible):
[image: **Schema**]

My challenge is to split columns - `assignee, inventor and ipcsubclass` using delimitor `|` into new tables {`detail_inv` and `inventors`}, {`detail_asg` and `assignees`} and {`detail_ipc` and `ipcsubclasses`}.

In all three cases, table schemas are similar. For example, columns on inventors table- `id` and `name` and on detail_inv table- `detail_id` and `inventor_id`.  There must be only one name per row with all names unique in inventors table and ids to hold relationship in detail_inv table.

I tried stored procedure with below code for inventors- I made 3 procedures for 3 columns:(

```
drop procedure if exists normalise_details;

delimiter #

create procedure normalise_details()
proc_main:begin

declare v_cursor_done int unsigned default 0;
declare v_post_id int unsigned;
declare v_tags varchar(2048);
declare v_keyword varchar(50);

declare v_keyword_id mediumint unsigned;

declare v_tags_done int unsigned;
declare v_tags_idx int unsigned;

declare v_cursor cursor for select id, inventor from details order by id;
declare continue handler for not found set v_cursor_done = 1;

set autocommit = 0; 

open v_cursor;
repeat

  fetch v_cursor into v_post_id, v_tags;
  set v_tags_done = 0;       
  set v_tags_idx = 1;

  while not v_tags_done do

    set v_keyword = substring(v_tags, v_tags_idx, 
      if(locate('|', v_tags, v_tags_idx) > 0, 
        locate('|', v_tags, v_tags_idx) - v_tags_idx, 
        length(v_tags)));

      if length(v_keyword) > 0 then

        set v_tags_idx = v_tags_idx + length(v_keyword) + 1;

        set v_keyword = trim(v_keyword);
        insert into inventors (name) values (v_keyword);

        select id into v_keyword_id from inventors where name = v_keyword;
        insert into details_inv (inventor_id, detail_id) values (v_keyword_id, v_post_id);

      else
        set v_tags_done = 1;
      end if;

  end while;

until v_cursor_done end repeat;

close v_cursor;

commit;

end proc_main #


delimiter ;
```

When I try this on some random test data, it works fine. when i do this on actual table, it doesn't work well.  Only partial data is inserted. SQL throws no errors (except for some times: "#1172 - Result consisted of more than one row" or "inventor_id column can't be null")

I tried modifying the code at
[MySQL - Insert comma separated list into normalized tables via stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763225/mysql-insert-comma-separated-list-into-normalized-tables-via-stored-procedure) to suit my needs but i failed.

Please help me,  my DB table has become a mess and there are about 500,000 rows making it really difficult for me to explode and manage huge arrays on each project(recent project with ~200,000 rows).

Comment: screenshot with better visibility is [here](http://prntscr.com/1ow7oz)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at RolandoMySQLDBA's post to this [dba.stackexchange question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10657/call-a-stored-procedure-from-a-trigger) I feel confirmed in my initial reservations regarding triggered stored procedures. However, if you are certain that at any given time only a *few lines* are changed by user input then it should be possible to put together a fast acting procedure.

However, if there are many users working in parallel they *might* still lock each other out. I don't know whether this will really happen since the stored procedure will not change anything in the `details` table. If necessary you could check out [this page](http://itecsoftware.com/with-nolock-table-hint-equivalent-for-mysql) for ideas.

**Edit:** TRIGGER

I just extended the SQLfiddle of my previous post to this [SQLfiddle with trigger](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b75e/1), containing the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER normdet AFTER INSERT ON detail FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE n int; DECLARE word VARCHAR(64)

 ;SET n=cntparts(NEW.inventor)
 ;WHILE n>0 DO
   SET word=part(new.inventor,n)
   ;IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inv WHERE invname=word) THEN
     INSERT INTO inv (invname) VALUES (word)
   ;END IF
   ;INSERT INTO det2inv (didid,diiid) 
    SELECT NEW.id,invid FROM inv WHERE invname=word
   ;SET n=n-1
 ;END WHILE
  -- and similar loops for assignee and cls ...
;END;
```

I also defined another function

```
CREATE FUNCTION cntparts (var varchar(1024)) RETURNS int
RETURN 1+LENGTH(var)-LENGTH(REPLACE(var,'|',''));
```

counting the words in a given `varchar`. This can also be used to create loops instead of my fixed `UNION` constructs for the base conversion in my first post.

The trigger now takes care of all new `INSERT`s. A similar trigger still needs to be written to do the same for `UPDATE`s. That should not be too hard to do ...

In my SQLfiddle I inserted another row into `detail` *after* the trigger definition. The results are listed by two comparative SELECT statements, see [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b75e/1).

**reply to last comment**:

Well, as I suggested in my original answer, you should first import all of the data (without having *any* triggers installed!!!!) and then plough through the `detail`-table with the `SELECT/UNION` statements. Before you do that you should find out the maximum number of words in each of the columns `assignee`,`inventor` and `ipsubclass` by using

```
SELECT MAX(cntparts(inventor)) invcnt,
       MAX(cntparts(assignee)) asscnt,
       MAX(cntparts(ipsubclass)) clscnt 
FROM detail
```

You can then adjust the number of `SELECT/UNION` statments needed for each column. Then fill the link tables as shown in the SQLfiddle.

Maybe the whole process takes a while but you can safely work on one table after another (first the actual attribute table and then the associated link-table).

*After that* you can activate your trigger which *should* then only work on *individually* added lines.

Comment: Thanks for the references,  in my case the data will be inserted on `details` table so it wont affect the users,  to further confirm the availability of table(s) to users,  there will be only 1 user inserting only 1 project at a time.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr You probably will have looked at the code by now, but yes, the trigger procedure *checks first* with `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inv WHERE invname=word)` before inserting an entry into the tables `inv` (and likewise for `assignee` and `cls`). In my example the name 'Beppu, Shiori' was inserted again into `detail` but *not* into `inv` again. But of course, the reference *was* set in `det2inv` for this new record.

Comment: Yes i did see the edited answer.  Thanks for your time and patience with me.  I was just trying this on my mySQL table.  You were right,  triggers causes a lot of overhead. Is there a way where I can do this after the data for a project is uploaded completely(data is imported in spreadsheet using phpMyAdmin) instead of each row.

Comment: As of now, this approach is the only solution I could accept.  You are right that it takes some time to do this for each table but it does the job at least.  Thanks for all your patience and kindness,  my hat off for you Sir.  I'll buy this answer because this refers to your original answer for bulk import and also provides a trigger to handle simple inserts.

Answer (score 2):

First of all it seems to me you should divide your table into four separate ones:

1. `detail` (main table, containing: `id, projectid,
   publicationnumber, prioritycountry, prioritydate` and `status`)
2. `inv`
   (inventor table, containing: `invid, invname` and possibly more
   inventor-related data)
3. `cls` (ipsubclass table, containing: `clsid,
   clsname` and possibly a description of each class)
4. `assignee` (containing data of assignee companies like: `assid, assname ...`)

Since there will be `n:m` relationships between the main table and the `inv, cls` and `assignee` you should also set up link tables holding the relationships like

- det2inv
- det2cls
- det2ass

The restructuring task can be broken down into several steps:

First of all you need to apply a user defined function for splitting the combined values. You can do that with a function as described [here](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/)

I simplifed it a bit further, since in your example we are only confronted with a single separator `|`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION part( x VARCHAR(255), pos INT) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(255) BEGIN
 DECLARE delim char(1)
 ;SET delim='|'
 ;RETURN TRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
                   LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, ''))
 ;END;
```

(Notice the `TRIM` function to chop away any unwanted blanks ...)

Next, you should define the target tables holding your inventors and possible ipsubclasses (... and assignees, which I have not done yet):

```
CREATE TABLE inv (invid int auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, invname nvarchar(64));
CREATE TABLE cls (clsid int auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, clsname nvarchar(6));
```

Feel free to extend the tables with additional columns, just as you need them.

Now we fill the tables with unique values. First the inventors in table `inv`:

```
INSERT INTO inv (invname) 
SELECT inv FROM (
 SELECT part(inventor,1) inv from detail
 UNION 
 SELECT part(inventor,2) from detail
 UNION 
 SELECT part(inventor,3) from detail
 UNION 
 SELECT part(inventor,4) from detail
 UNION 
 SELECT part(inventor,5) from detail
 UNION 
 SELECT part(inventor,6) from detail
 UNION 
 SELECT part(inventor,7) from detail
 UNION 
 SELECT part(inventor,8) from detail
) t WHERE inv>'' ORDER BY inv;
```

next the ipsubclasses:

```
INSERT INTO cls (clsname)
SELECT icls FROM (
 SELECT part(iclass,1) icls from detail
 UNION 
 SELECT part(iclass,2) from detail
 UNION 
 SELECT part(iclass,3) from detail
 UNION 
 SELECT part(iclass,4) from detail
 UNION 
 SELECT part(iclass,5) from detail
 UNION 
 SELECT part(iclass,6) from detail
 UNION 
 SELECT part(iclass,7) from detail
 UNION 
 SELECT part(iclass,8) from detail
) t WHERE icls>'' ORDER BY icls;
```

In my example I only looked at the first 8 entries of each field. This can be modified to suit your needs of course. You will end up with two uniquely numbered tables containing all possible inventors and all possible ipsubclasses (and in an analogous way all assignees). You can have a look at my SQLfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aeafe/1

The remaining task is now to fill the link tables with suitable keys (pairs of ids from main table `details` and its attribute tables `inv, cls`and `assignee`.

**Edit**

The link tables are being filled with the following statements:

```
INSERT INTO det2inv (didid,diiid)
SELECT id,invid FROM inv 
INNER JOIN detail ON INSTR(inventor,invname)>0;

INSERT INTO det2cls (dcdid,dccid)
SELECT id,clsid FROM cls 
INNER JOIN detail ON INSTR(iclass,clsname)>0;

-- ... and a similar one for det2ass
```

The `INSTR()` function will not work perfectly as names like `Hagen, Pete` will be matched successfully against `Gleichenhagen, Peter`. To avoid these cases the comparison should be modifed as shown here:

```
...
INNER JOIN detail ON INSTR(REPLACE(CONCAT('|',inventor,'|'),' ',''),
                           REPLACE(CONCAT('|',invname,'|'),' ',''))>0;
```

You can see the **complete working example** here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/097be/8

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation and a very nice illustration using fiddles. I will go and check how this works in my situation and report back here, though, I doubt about the performance of this approach for my huge data. A problem with this code for me is that I can't say about number of delimiters in column, it can be 0-80. Is doing `UNION` 80 times a good idea? The table schema you suggested is exactly as I made(and mentioned in question :) see next comment also.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to do this using a stored procedure because I keep receiving new data into `details` which I can't control. So, my plan was to write a stored procedure and make a trigger to run it every time a new project comes in.  I really can't depend on running this function manually.

Comment: So far I have no experience with triggers. I kept off them because I years ago I observed a situation where a colleague of mine had serious performance problems caused by locks imposed by (slow running) triggered stored procedures. I assume though, in your case it would be feasible to do the triggered transformation of incoming/changed lines as this will only need to work on a previously selected set of rows. I will have another look at it ...

Comment: Thanks @cars10.  I will wait for your updated answer or a new answer.

Comment: does the UDF ignore inserts of already existing inventors/assignees/ipcclasses in the tables.  I mean, for example, if name ABC corp. already exists in table assignees due to data for project 1, will it be ignored when the same name is found in project 2 or will it be inserted again?